# In Linux, how can I print output for a text file once it's created?

Tags: linux, cat, tail

I have a file called /home/myuser/tmp* that is briefly created, logs an output message and is then deleted. I need to see that output, but it's only there for a second at most (I'm working with an annoying open source program). Is there some command like "tail -f /home/myuser/tmp*" that can show me the contents of that file as soon as it's created?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening another terminal and write a loop that attempts to copy the file.
Start it right before the operation that causes the file to be created.  Once the creation script is done, CTRL-C to kill the loop in the other session and see if it created the saved file.  You may have to try it a couple of times but it should capture that file at some point!

```
while :
do
  cp /home/myuser/tmpfile /home/myuser/tmpfile.sav 2>/dev/null
done
```

Maybe the process that creates the file just appends to it if it already exists.  If so, and if you know what the name of it will be, create an empty file by that name and do the `tail -f` of it in another terminal session, then run the program in the first terminal. Not in a loop, just a `tail -f tmpfile`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other activity in /home/myuser, you could simply do:

```
inotifywait -e close /home/myuser && cat '/home/myuser/tmp*'
```

(Is the file name really `tmp*`, or are you asking about arbitrarily named files that begin with `tmp`?  If the latter, this solution clearly will not work.

Inotifywait will simply block until some file in `/home/myuser` is closed, and then `cat` the file.  If you want to watch for multiple files, you might prefer something like:

```
inotifywait -m -e close_write --format %f ~myuser | 
    while read file; do cat ~myuser/$file; done
```

But note the standard warnings and caveats about paths containing whitespace.